# Ambiguity in sprintf about returning '%' character

Tags: c, printf

I have to output a string which starts with % character (%EE#WD...) and I'm using sprintf. In multiple references, I'v read that using a % after % specifier, causes sprintf function to return the % character.

But for me, in different compilers (like DEV C++, JDOODLE) the result is not what I expected and finally I got the % character by repeating the % specifier for 4 times!

What's the reason?

Here is the code and outputs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    static char Command[10]   ;
    sprintf (Command,"%%EE#") ;
    printf  (Command)         ;    
    return 0                  ;
}
```

Output:
**3.205269E-317E#**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    static char Command[10]     ;
    sprintf (Command,"%%%%EE#") ;
    printf  (Command)           ;    
    return 0                    ;
}
```

Output:
**%EE#**

Thanks.

Comment: @xing - that would indeed be the issue, if you explain a bit more it would make a great answer

Comment: first sprintf `"%%%%EE#"` -> `"%%EE#"`. The second printf as it is the format string `"%%EE#"` -> `"%EE#"`. To print the string use puts instead. It is much faster anyway.

Comment: @xing thanks a lot. I got the point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After `sprintf (Command,"%%EE#")`, `Command` will contain `%EE#`. If you now pass this content to `printf` as a format string, the (now) single `%` will be interpreted as a format specifier, looking for a float argument then. This is not provided and leads actually to undefined behaviour. With `sprintf (Command,"%%%%EE#")`, you "overcome" this problem since `Command` will contain `%%EE#` then.

But actually you should write...

```
static char Command[10] = "%EE#";
printf  ("%s",Command);
```

Or...

```
static char Command[10];
strcpy(Command,"%EE#");
printf  ("%s",Command);
```

Comment: ... or use `puts()` or `fputs()` if you want to output a string as-is, without engaging the formatting machinery.

Comment: @JohnBollinger A good compiler will emit the same efficient code for `printf  ("%s",Command);` and `fputs(Command, stdout);`.  IMO, code for clarity and let the compiler handle such linear optimizations.

Comment: @chux, I submit that using `fputs(Command, stdout)` instead of `printf ("%s",Command)` *is* coding for clarity.  That is, in fact, my point.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I read the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54056946/ambiguity-in-sprintf-about-returning-character/54057031?noredirect=1#comment94948050_54057031) as a point about  code efficiency, not clarity.  What looks most clear in one context differs and depends on neighboring code.  IAC, we agree that clarity is a driving issue.  In general, I too  find `fputs()` better, yet near many non-trivial `printf()` lines-of-code, I find `printf ("%s",Command)` more clear.  ... And expect my compiler to do a good job.

Answer (score 3):

Passing the result of `sprintf` as the first argument to `printf` causes it to be reinterpreted as a format string. Thus, your string is interpret as a format string once for `sprintf` and again for `printf`. Do not do this.

If you do not need formatting, just print a string with `fputs`, as in `fputs("%EE#", stdout);`. (`puts` is similar, but it appends a new-line character. `fputs` just prints the characters it is given.)

If you need formatting and can print directly (without an intermediate buffer), use `printf`; do not use `sprintf` beforehand.

If you need to formatting and need the result written to a buffer, then use `sprintf` and print the buffer with `fputs`, not `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sprintf (Command,"%%EE#") ;
printf  (Command)         ;
```

*%%* in a format is the way to ask to print *%*, so *%%EE#* produces *%EE#*

so after as xing said in a remark *printf(command)* works on *%EE#* like if you do directly *printf("%EE#")*, and the arg is missing so the result for "%E" is random

```
sprintf (Command,"%%%%EE#") ;
printf  (Command)           ;
```

*sprintf* set command with "%%EE#" so after you have the result of `printf("%%EE#")` being %EE#

Comment: Indeed, but that's not what is printed by the *next* line for the reason @xing explained

Comment: yes, of course, printf(command) get the previous result as a format

Comment: @ChrisStratton I edited my answer, when something is implied I have the bad habit of not saying it in my answer, I have trouble correcting myself

Answer (score 0):

`%%` will give you `%` the `%E` actually refers to scientific notation that's why your getting a number and need more `%` to print out `%E`

Comment: Only because it is being interpreted twice for the reason @xing pointed out.  What you are proposing is not really the right fix, unless the goal is to programmatically generate a format string, which while *possible* is not what is wanted here, and not usually a good idea.